# A special grammatical function of "me"

Tags: grammar

In a book I read about all kinds of behavioural oddities people displayed when travelling alone. Then the author continued to mention his own idiosyncrasies by writing "Me, I get a sort of interrogative diarrhoea, I ask private, internal questions (...)". What, I wonder, is the function of/grammatical term for "me"?

Comment: The function and grammatical term for it is 'appositive'. The reason for it being accusative is, well, like lots of grammar, just the way it is.

Comment: @Mitch What is it appositive to? Not 'I' – it is in a different syntactical position (contrast _Mr Cameron, the Prime Minister, yesterday said that ..._ where either of the appositives may be dropped). It's a pragmatic  focussing device (and short for 'As for me' etc). 'Remember that the appositive [noun phrase] and the noun to which it refers always share the same four properties--gender, number, person, and case--since they both name the same entity [in the same syntactic role]."
(Michael Strumpf and Auriel Douglas, The Grammar Bible. Owl Books, 2004)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as an abbreviation, e.g.

"When it comes to me, I get a sort of interrogative diarrhoea..."

English Idiomatic Expression: [“When it comes to…”](http://englishharmony.com/when-it-comes-to/) by Robby   on October 31, 2012

... or "With regard to me, ..."

Comment: Why the down-vote? I'd prefer a constructive comment to show where and if  I went wrong.

Comment: Also _As for me._ Think of it as a bullet-point label. _Him, he isn't fast enough; the other one, almost; but me, I'm faster than either_.

Comment: Yes, "As for me" was the expression that I really wanted. I couldn't quite bring it to mind. Much better.

Comment: Ah, the DBDV (drive-by down-vote), a plague upon this site.  But we wouldn't want to compromise the anonymity of the lazy and cowardly, dontchaknow.